# Making chart with related table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, table, relates, chart

I have a feature class with some locations of drills. I also have a table with data how deep the drill went and some more technical data in it.

I used relate on the feature class to connect the feature class with the table. 
I am trying to make a linechart of the data of this table and I want to show this chart in the popup.

There is no option to select the fields of the table (related) as a X or Y axis.

Anyone know how to make a chart based on the related table?

[image]